git pull origin main on wrong branch: divergent branches
I was on a feature branch abc and thought I was on main. Then I ran git pull origin main. Now I have the error You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
Searching for this error message, I get a lot of posts about what to do if you encounter this error in the normal course of business, like if you actually were on main instead of accidentally on a feature branch. But what should one do if the problem is that you were on the wrong branch?
In other words, how may I undo whatever I did when I ran git pull origin main?

Do you need to do anything? If it doesn't know if you want to merge or rebase, I guess it does neither.

Remove the repo, check it out fresh, and it should work

There's nothing to undo. Git is telling you that the pull failed. For you, that's good! You want to have failed; when you said git pull origin main, you didn't mean it. And Git didn't do it! So all is well.
